# Static property of PHP class to keep value until next usage?

Tags: php

I just stumbled over a PHP class and wonder if there was a valid reason for the way one of it's methods is written.

`LogUtility::getLogger()` is called as a static method in various other PHP classes of the PHP application. Does the used `if` statement make sense or is `$logManager` always `null` when `getLogger()` is called?

```
class LogUtility
{
    /**
     * @var LogManager
     */
    protected static $logManager;

    /**
     * @return Logger
     */
    public static function getLogger($name)
    {
        if (!self::$logManager) {
            self::$logManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(LogManager::class);
        }
        return self::$logManager->getLogger($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a small test.  Does it? Or doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quickly whip up a test, like below, and test / prove it yourself:

```
class someClass {
    protected static $stored;

    public static function test() {
        echo '<br>Stored state:' . self::$stored;
        if ( ! self::$stored) {
             self::$stored = "set";
        }
    }
}

someClass::test();
someClass::test();
```

Output is:

> Stored state:
>     Stored state:set

So, based on this simple test, the answer is **Yes**, the `if` statement makes sense.  The static variable is set and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

`$logManager` is set to a property of the class, so for now, its pretty much an empty class, just returning with a getter, the instance. This just sets the code to just **reuse** the object.  So a bit of **recycling** code there.

In the class you are now able to play with this object freely.  So if you run this `LogUtility` from another piece of code by setting it to a var, you have already instantiated it. e.g. `$util = new LogUtility();`now if someone comes along and tries to instantiate it again, `$anotherUtil=new LogUtility();` this recycles the class, passing back the already instantiated instance, instead of instantiating a new one.

Therefore, **yes**, it kept it. Although, the var doesn't contain the "same value" per say, it contains a reference to the "same" class that was instantiated with he other variable, so it ends up a copy of the same instance there.

Answer (score 0):

It will be null for only the first call in a lifecycle. This implements a design pattern called Singleton.

Check out https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/php/1